# How to merge two branches where the target has different folder hierarchy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have source branch `A`. I branched `B` from it.

in `B` I have **moved** some folders under another physical folder named `TB`.

Now I want to merge from `A` to `B`, but the hierarchy had changed for some folders.

How can I solve this?

I tried to create temporary TB folder in `A` as well, but merging didn't work.
see:
[image]

Comment: no code example. Only mismatch hierarchy.

Comment: Have you tried the merge? I'm a little surprised that TFS doesn't understand that you performed _Rename_ operations on folders.

Comment: I can verify TFS sucks in this regard. It doesn't understand how to merge rename operations.

Comment: You should be able to `tf merge` with source and target paths that are different relative to the root of each branch, then do the rename in `A` separately.

Comment: Tfs sucks wrt merging. Rather than wasting time trying to find an automated solution that will almost certainly screw everything up, I'd do a manual merge file by file. Unfortunately the best practice with tfs is to avoid renames or defer them until the safest possible opportunity, check them in with no other changes, and merge them immediately if possible.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I meant to merge from A to B

Comment: You can still `tf merge` with different relative source and target paths, at least for the folders whose names have changed in the target branch.

Comment: I agree with John Saunders. I did the same thing earlier today. Moved some folders in my dev branch and then merged with main. No problem. After I checked in the changes to main the folder structure was correct. Can you give a bit more info about what your seeing in the target branch?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have tried see the attached photo. I didn't rename. I added new folder in the path

Comment: What exactly did you do when you "changed the hierarchy"?  Can you show the history of the files that are conflicting?

Comment: Also, please tell us how you created the branches. Did you create them in TFS 2010? It does a much better job with branching than TFS 2008 did, as it actually understands branches as full-fledged objects. Also, how did you do the moves? They should have been "Rename" operations against the folders: to move "$/X" and $"/Y" under "$/Z", that should have been "Add $/Z", "Rename $/X to $/Z/X", "Rename $/Y to $/Z/Y". I would expect it to remember the renames when it comes time to merge.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis in what console should I type tf merge cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you deleted a file from A and are now trying to merge the file from B back into A.  It doesn't appear to be squawking about a newly added or renamed directory.

Quite frankly it looks like you branched A => B.  Then moved stuff around in A and are now trying to merge B back into it... with the files in the old location in B.

I would just pick "restore the file and merge my changes from B".